# Zingchart with angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, include, append, zingchart

I use zingchart with angular, It works perfect when I display a chart in a single page, but when I try to include the template with zingchart in a tab, It doesn't show and I don't have any error in a browser's console,

HTML :

```
<div zingchart id="chart-1" zc-json="myJson"></div>
```

CONTROLLER of zingchart's view:

```
$scope.myJson = {
type: "line",
series : [
                    {
                        values : data1,
                        text : "A",
                        lineColor : "#00ACF2",
                        marker : {
                            borderColor : "#00ACF2"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        values : data2,
                        text : "B",
                        lineColor : "#86CA00",
                        marker : {
                            borderColor: "#86CA00"
                        }
                    }
                ]
};
```

CONTROLLER that I use to include my view with zingchart :

```
$templateRequest(template).then(function (html) { 
var template = angular.element(html); 
contenu = $compile(template)($scope); 
$timeout(function () { $('#onglet').append(contenu); }, 100); 
});
```

Thank you

Comment: I use angular zingchart directive https://github.com/zingchart/ZingChart-AngularJS and the code I use for include :  $templateRequest(template).then(function (html) {
                var template = angular.element(html);
                contenu = $compile(template)($scope);
    $timeout(function () {
     $('#onglet').append(contenu);
    }, 100);
        });

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could update the original question with all the code you are running with your directive.

Comment: I added the code, thank you

Comment: Check out our new Angular directive [update](https://blog.zingchart.com/2016/08/12/angularjs-directive-v1-1-0/). It takes care of chart cleanup in memory so this may alleviate your issue.

Comment: It was because of "id" zingchart element, the new angular directive resolved my issue, thank you